How can I repair a severely rusted wrought iron railing?
I have an outdoor wrought iron railing that is in terrible condition, but we would like to do minimal repairs to keep it at least somewhat less an eyesore, to stop rust spread, and get some structural safety until we can afford a better replacement.
It looks like a previous repair was attempted by welding or attaching a new railing atop the original failing railing, but the rust was never removed so continued to erode. In one place, the spindle is completely rusted from the top of the railing. I've only got basic tools on hand, no welder.
The process I think to try to mend this is:

Grind off rust with a wire wheel
Grab a square aluminum tube from the home center, cut it as best as I can to fit underneath the functional plate and somewhat hold the ballusters in place
Slather the metals with epoxy and clamp them down.
Prime and paint.

My concerns are: would epoxy bond aluminum to bare steel?


the car is in focus, not the iron ... why did you post that picture? ... did you not look at it?

You can epoxy dissimilar metals; they won't corrode each other if they do not make direct contact.
Other DIY options would be to assemble railings using galvanized steel pipe (plumbing department) or treated lumber (deck railings, etc.).
But given the safety risks, I would bite the bullet and go ahead with the final replacement. Money saved by skipping the temp solution will help offset the cost.

Just to offer an option to the square tubing, I bought steel stakes to fit inside the legs of my railing. Cutting them to size allowed for 6" to extend into the hole in the (concrete) steps. Epoxy worked well to join the metal and bind it firmly in the hole.
